# Visual Studio Online - I just can't handle it...?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I hope that StackOverflow can help me with this problem, even if it's not 100% a programming question.

I've created a Visual Studio Online Account so I can manage my Code from everywhere and can share it with my buddies. There is just one problem:
Even though I have read al the Microsoft help about for days, I can't manage to simply create a new TeamProject with code and everything. You really are my last chance to understand it. At the moment, I have deleted all my failed attempts, there are no projects currently on my Account.

When going online, a question prompt appears asking me to create a new project. I enter a name, easy. I don't know what a Process Template is but Scrum sounds most like what I am searching for. It asks me whether I want to use GIT or TFVC. I want to use TFVC as I'm only working with Visual Studio 2013 and I think it's easier to use with it.

It says that my project is now in the cloud and asks me what to do next. I want to "add code", so I click it. Now there's a folder named "BuildProcessTemplate". I don't know how to add code or create a normal Visual Studio project. If I create a new project offline and click "Add to version control", it doesn't add it and if I connect to VS with another PC I can't find the code I wrote.

How am I supposed to simply create a normal project, write code and upload it after? And how can I change it with another PC after that?

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the barrier you hit is, that you chose to use a local workspace (instead of a server workspace) and did not yet map it to a local folder. TFS will not allow you to add anything until you mapped the Team Collection (or a sub-folder) to a local workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio 2013 on your machine, click on "View" in the File menu along the top, then select "Team Explorer". That should open a window with the team explorer. Click on "Connect to Team Projects" (it's an icon that looks like a US plug socket). Then click "Select Team Projects..." and enter your details for your vs online account. That should get you going...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I followed your steps, but what do I have to do now?

Comment: So, you should see your newly created project in that dialog now. Click it to open it. You should then be given the option to clone the repository, once that is done you can add/delete/edit the project files in Visual Studio. This isnt really a suitable SO question so Im sure one of the mods will point that out shortly..you can pm me on oferns at googles free email facility...(hint gmail)

Comment: whats your gmail adress?

Comment: You should be able to deduce it from the comment :) "oferns at googles free email facility"